# Get elements from JSON array in random order

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, plpgsql

Using PostgreSQL 9.4, I store data as JSON array in plpgsql code, for example:

```
j := '[1,2,3,4,5]'::json
```

Next I loop through this array and do something with digits.

```
FOR i1 IN 0..(json_array_length(j)-1) LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE 'i1=%', j->>(i1);
END LOOP;
```

I get this output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I get a random sort order for the loop? Like:

```
3
5
1
2
4
```

Comment: I've got to ask ... why? What's the underlying task, the problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Imagine array of image IDs, some time I want see images sorted by ID, some time random. Client who get image array is third party and I can't controll sequence on their side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple, just use `json_array_elements_text` and `ORDER BY random()`.

```
  DECLARE
    item text
  BEGIN
    FOR item IN
      SELECT json_array_elements_text('[1,2,3,4,5]'::json) ORDER BY random()
    LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE 'item is %',item;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make new array of keys (from 0 to 4)

```sql
SELECT INTO intarray array_agg(s.n)
FROM (SELECT generate_series(0,json_array_length(j)-1) AS n
ORDER BY random()) s
```

2. In main loop get values from j array by value from new array

```sql
FOR i1 IN 0..(json_array_length(j)-1) LOOP

   RAISE NOTICE 'i1=%', j->>(intarray[i1]);

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generate_series():

```
select '[1,2,3,4,5]'::json->>(i) 
from generate_series(0, 4) i
order by random();
```